# Azure Graph Storage account blob containers

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have this Azure Graph query to get all my storage accounts:

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.storage/storageaccounts'
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name)
    on subscriptionId
| project name,sku,properties,tags,resourceGroup,tenantId,subscriptionId,location,subscriptionName
```

Now I need to get for each storage account the Containers names and "Public Access Level" for each of them, like in this picture from Azure Portal:

[image: Azure Portal example image]

I can't find the right query in Azure Graph to do it. Any help?

Comment: @alferdoFernandez, As per my understanding you cannot pull the list of containers and their access level in a storage account using the resource graph explorer queries 
Below are the list of properties that can be pulled using the graph explorer queries as  shown in image. 
https://i.imgur.com/YKoQZUb.png

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT Ok, then what you mean is that this is a limitation in Azure Graph, where the containers are not part of the data model, right?

Comment: @Alferdo Fernandez - yes, you cannot pull the container list inside the storage account using resource graph explorer. You might have to use any powershell script to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best answer, but I did using Graph and doing so, **looping** btw containers in each Storage with something like this:

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $_.resourceGroup -Name $_.name
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

$container = Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$container = $container | Where-Object -Property PublicAccess -ne "Off"
    foreach ($c in $container) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ResourceGroup  = $_.resourceGroup
            StorageAccount = $_.name
            BlobPublicAccess = $_.allowBlobPublicAccess
            Container = $c.Name
            ContainerPublicAccess = $c.PublicAccess
        }        
    }
```